# Unwanted saw tooth waveform on DC rails

Tags: transformer, rectifier, sawtooth-waveform

I am somewhat new to electronics and am building up a dual rail power supply.  Under no load the DC rails sit at about +15V and -15V.  Please refer to the schematic and oscilloscope screenshot (below) for the following discussion.

I discovered a saw tooth waveform sitting on top of both DC rails.  This saw tooth waveform is a problem as it grows in amplitude with increased load (22mA = 50mVpp, 0.6A = 700mVpp).  At a 3A load the amplitude of the saw tooth waveform is greater than 4Vpp.

I do not understand the origins of this saw tooth waveform.  Why is it there?  What is generating it?

The saw tooth waveform appears on either rail when a load is attached to that rail.

The saw tooth waveform is not discernible on the oscilloscope when no load is attached.

If I replace the transformer and the rectifier with a commercial DC power supply, but keep a load in the circuit, the saw tooth waveform is not present.

It seems that the combination of a rectifier and a transformer and a circuit load generate this issue but I do not have a clue why.

I tried full bridge rectifiers, transformer, and capacitors from different manufacturers but got the same result.

I thought maybe this could be the result of inductive coupling of the AC wires to the DC wires.  To that end I isolated as best I could all wires and the transformer but there was no change in the presence or amplitude of this saw tooth waveform (for a given load).

Any help in understanding why this issue exists would be greatly appreciated.  If this issue is inherent in this design, I would very much appreciate any ideas on how to filter it out or even design changes to avoid this issue in the first place.

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Logical. It is the ripple in such circuits and is quasi proportional to current load. Use some regulators to help. Note that you will get lower voltage. You can use also some switching regulators that can use quasi any voltage at input to output quasi any voltage at output (automatic buck-boost).

Comment: Note also that generally, negative voltage are less used than positive. See for example the specs of PC desktop supplies.

Comment: I suggest that you look at the many examples given via the link in my answer.

Comment: The ripple is at 100 Hz? Are you in Europe or a country with 50 Hz power? I was expecting to see 60/120 Hz ripple :-)

Comment: @KenShirriff This does not "really" matter (100 or 120 are not really "different". Quasi-same phenomena.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The sawtooth waveform on an unregulated power supply is normal. Internally even commercial regulated power supplies have this waveform on the input to the regulated section. The sawtooth is created by the charge and discharge of the smoothing capacitor. Greater load currents will discharge the capacitor more quickly and by doing so increases the amplitude of the saw tooth. See the image below from [Electronic-Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_6.html).

The ripple cannot be avoided, It can be reduced by increasing the smoothing capacitance within limits.

[image]

To prevent propagating to the output terminals a regulator is placed between the unregulated output and the terminals as shown below in the image from [ElProCus](https://www.elprocus.com/bridge-rectifier-circuit-theory-with-working-operation/). The voltage input to the regulator must be high enough so that at full load, the voltage at the bottom of the ripple is greater than Vout plus the headroom required by the regulator.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see!  Thanks for the explanation.  Very helpful!  So in terms of ripple rejection ratio of a voltage regulator, can I use this equation: PSRR = 20 log (Vri / Vro).  If so, then if I have a ripple of 4Vpp and I have a voltage regulator ripple rejection ratio of 66db, would that mean that the ripple should be attenuated by a factor of 1995 (1mV)?  Or conversely, if I have a voltage regulator output ripple of 4Vpp, would that mean that the input ripple amplitude is 3990V (4/2*1995)?

Comment: If the low point of the ripple takes the voltage below the minimum voltage required for the regulator to work, the regulator will "pass on" the ripple to the output.  For a 78xx regulator, the input voltage must be 2 volts or more for the regulator to work.  For a 7805, if the input voltage drops below about 7 volts, the output voltage will also drop during the dips in the input voltage.  There are "Low Dropout" regulators that will continue to regulate with less "headroom" than the 78xx family.

Answer (score 3):

Others will provide a far fuller answer, but this is fundamental to such simple rectifier circuits. The rectifier alone provides a series of positive half sinusoids. The filter capacitor smooths this to DC under no load, but any load that draws current when the bridge rectifier output is below the capacitor voltage will cause the voltage to fall as the cap discharges. The capacitor leakage current and rectifier reverse leakage may be enough to account for the no load ripple.

A larger filter capacitor will help somewhat BUT as Antonio51 says, a regulator following the Bridge Rectifier and filter capacitors is the usual solution.

You can get SOME improvement by using a CLC filter - ie a cap to ground on either side of a series inductor BUT a regulator is easier and cheaper.

There are many example circuits [**here**](https://www.google.com/search?q=full+wave+rectifier+with+regulator&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ALiCzsYSuERGqdaV7NhVx8A_WjZyy6DboA:1671366191269&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjP1vqglIP8AhWKqVYBHaTUCNwQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1920&bih=1009&dpr=2) - each image links to a web page.

Adding a small series resistor in the line from bridge rectifier to capacitor - maybe 10 ohms(experment) may help somewhat as it spreads the capacitor charging period and will somewhat reduce the absolute cycle by cycle peak value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Very helpful.  Yes I was looking at LRC filters but I am having problems finding an inductor with a high enough inductance and a low enough DC resistance.   Since these are power rails I want a DC resistance of no more than a few tens on mOhms.  Anyway, this all leads to another larger problem I am having with the voltage output of a voltage regulator at "high" loads (>2.75A).  I'll have to create a new post for this.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Pat  You do not want R in the main filter except as an unavoidable part of L . The small series "spreading resistors" widen rectifier conduction angle and are useful but not part of the filtering action as such - they just make it easier. They come BEFORE any capacitors.

Answer (score 3):

I am just pointing here something you must be aware ...
Switching on such supply lead initially to a "big" current.
So a little resistor should be use to limit this.

[image]

Comment: Wow, yes, thank you for the analysis.  Do I read your analysis of the initial capacitor current correctly?  Around 34A?  Is that a single program you are using to do this analysis?

Comment: Yes 34A when voltage is on at phase 0°, it it could be bigger if "switch on" occurs at 90°. There are some programs to do such analysis. I use free microcap v12 http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm

Comment: @Pat You should be aware that your real circuit won't behave exactly like this ideal simulation. Your transformer has resistance that was not included in the simulation, so the initial current will be much smaller.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Right. Just pointed out the problem for checking (all currents, voltages and powers) the complete circuit with well-known specifications and complete parameters of transformers & components.

Comment: You can find now FREE microcap v12 at https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110